# Programming C# Windows form IF else statement on ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

Given: 4 combo box named cboType, cboFloor, cboRoom, cboRate .

## Here is the condition.

if i choose Bedspace in cboType,

```
 the cboFloor will only appear "1",
 the cboRoom will only appear the list of Rooms in Floor 1,
 the cboRate will only appear "1000".
```

Comment: Global Question: What have you tried?

Comment: You can use `SelectedValueChangedEvent` of `cboType` and change text of others

Comment: nothing, im  still new to this language

Comment: Would be best if you can learn the fundamentals. To start with I suggest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Agree with Joel, here's a website a lot of beginners have found useful in my experience: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html

Comment: btw, i created a database in  (phpmy admin) . i successfuly linked the code to the database... how ever, my system still doesnt meet the requirement

Comment: are there any possibility to retrieve my data from phpmyAdmin to dataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cboFloor.Items.Add("1");
cboRoom.Items.Add("Floor 1");
cboRate.Items.Add("1000");
```

this is your Answer?

Comment: data are recorded in my database (phpmyadmin mysql). so i think it is not necessary to use Items.add(); anymore

Comment: Thank you for your help :) .